# Conditional Compilation not working

Tags: go, build

OS: linux/amd64
GO: 1.5.1

When running (`go run *.go`) the below code I get the following error and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've read the [official doc](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) about build constrains. Shouldn't `foo_windows.go` be ignored?

```
# command-line-arguments
./foo_windows.go:3: hello redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ./foo_linux.go:3
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(hello())
}
```

**foo_linux.go**

```
package main

func hello() string {
    return "hello form linux"
}
```

**foo_windows.go**

```
package main

func hello() string {
    return "hello form windows"
}
```

Comment: `go run` takes an explicit list of files to compile; it does not check the filename for any potential build constrains. You will notice that running `go build` on your package will work without error.

Comment: But it will work with the windows file too... I noticed that when moving `hello` to another package, everything works as expected.

Comment: `go run` is a convenience tool for a file or two. Use `go install` or `go build`.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. Please add an answer so that I can mark the question as resolved.